# how to solve first order non linear differential equation of the following form

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have an equation of the following form

$$y'=\frac{1}{(x+y^{-m/2})(a-x)^{2}}$$

where $a,m$ are constants and $x<a$ and variable are $x,y$. Also, $m$ is an integer. How to solve the above equation? I know its a first order nonlinear differential equation with non-separable variables. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Moo I do not know. Have you seen any problem that has similar kind of structure?

Comment: @Moo Thank you for your comment. Do you know any approximation methods or any bounding methods that can be used to obtain some approximate (or lower/upper bounds) of the solution?